# Is it possible to dual-sign installer and uninstaller with sha1 and sha256 certificates?

Tags: inno-setup, signtool, verisign

Is it possible in Inno Setup to sign the Uninstaller and Installer with sha1 and sha256 at the same time?

I know that it is [possible to sign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30671378/1329977) the Executable with both certs via command tool, but want to know if this is possible to achieve with `SignTool` in Inno.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? You can pass a batch file as your signtool which calls signtool.exe two times.

Answer (score 11):

Autoanswer...

Yes, this is possible. As @Wosi suggested you can write a batch and then call it with `$f` parameter added.

Sample batch (signtool.bat):

```
@echo off

"PATH_TO_SIGNTOOL\signtool.exe" sign /v /du "COMPANY_NAME" /fd sha1 /t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" /f "sha1_cert.pfx" /p PASSWORD %1

set SIGN_RESULT_1=%ERRORLEVEL%

"PATH_TO_SIGNTOOL\signtool.exe" sign /as /v /du "COMPANY_NAME" /fd sha256 /tr "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161" /td sha256 /f "sha256_cert.pfx" /p PASSWORD %1

set SIGN_RESULT_2=%ERRORLEVEL%

set /a RESULT=%SIGN_RESULT_1%+%SIGN_RESULT_2%

if %RESULT% NEQ 0 (
   echo Warning! Signing failed with %SIGN_RESULT_1% for sh1 and %SIGN_RESULT_2% for sha256
   pause
   exit /B %RESULT%
) 

echo Signing succeeded
exit /B 0
```

Then in Inno Setup you can call `signtool.bat $f` where `$f` will be passed to `%1` for the batch.

For Windows XP compatibility for *sha1*: removed `/as`, `/tr` replaced with `/t`, removed `/td` (as it requires `/tr`)

I will leave it here as maybe someone could find it helpful.

Comment: While this works, note that [since Inno Setup 5.5.8](http://jrsoftware.github.io/issrc/whatsnew.htm#5.5.8), you can have multiple [`SignTool` directives](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_signtool.htm), as the [answer by @TheArtTrooper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38753662/850848) shows.

Comment: I had some compilation errors – need to write full path: c:\...\signtool.bat $f

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Inno Setup 5.5.9. I compile my script from the command line using `ISCC`. My setup script includes these two lines in the `[Setup]` section:

```
SignTool=sha1
SignTool=sha256
```

The `ISCC` command looks like:

```
ISCC "/ssha1=signtool.exe /f <cert.pfx> /p <certpwd> /fd SHA1 /t <timestamp.url> /v $f" "/ssha256=signtool.exe /f <cert.pfx> /p <certpwd> /fd SHA256 /tr <timestamp.url> /td SHA256 /as /v $f" setup.iss
```

Inno Setup will sign the install and uninstall with both certs.